# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable - apriori

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm building code for randonmised algorithm. When I tried to run this code by python3 random.py -f T10I4D100K.dat -p 0.1 -s 0.05 -c 0.05, it causes TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. Which part should I change?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "random.py", line 48, in 
     `main()`
  File "random.py", line 41, in main
    `file_to_array()`
  File "random.py", line 32, in file_to_array
    `if (decision(args.probability)):`
  File "random.py", line 19, in decision
    `return random.random() < float(probability)`
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

```
import argparse
import time
import sys
import random
from efficient_apriori import apriori
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="datasets")
parser.add_argument('-f', '--file', 
default="sample.txt",help="http://fimi.uantwerpen.be/data/")
parser.add_argument('-s', '--min_support', default = 0.5,
                help="minimum support, set to 0.5 by default")
parser.add_argument('-c', '--min_confidence', default = 0.5,
                help="minimum confidence, set to 1 by default")
parser.add_argument('-p', '--probability', default = 1,
                help="Probability for randomlized slice")               
args = parser.parse_args()
#memory_data [Brisket_Number][Item_Number]
memory_data = []
data_list = []
def decision(probability):
    return random.random() < float(probability)
#------------------------------------------File Handling------------------------------------------
def file_to_array():
    i = 1
    data_file = open(args.file, "r")
    print("Reading File into Array...\n")
    #if its comment line
    for line in data_file:

        line = line.rstrip()
        line_row = line.split()

        memory_data.append(line_row)
        if (decision(args.probability)):
            data_list.append(tuple(line_row))
        i += 1
    data_file.close()
    #print("Array:",memory_data,"\n")
    #print("Data_list:",data_list)
    print ("Reading complete ",i, " lines in total.")
def main():
    start_time = time.time()
    file_to_array()
    #Apriori()
    itemsets, rules = apriori(data_list, min_support= float(args.min_support),  
min_confidence=float(args.min_confidence))
    #print(itemsets)
    print(rules) 
    print("--- Total run time: %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You also need to share error traceback to be able to help you.

Comment: See if you can create a [mcve].

Comment: I just added traceback

Answer (score 0):

Your module is named `random.py`. When you import `random` into your module, you're actually importing your own module. It creates a global name `random` in your module which is also called `random`.

This line of code fails:

```
return random.random() < float(probability)
```

The first `random` is your module. The second `random` is the name defined by the import random statement.

Comment: so I need to change the module name random.py to something else. right?

Comment: That would fix the problem.